# how to determine the Big-O notation of this equation?

Tags: big-o

0.0001*2^n + 10 * n^2 + 10000 * log(n) + 10000000

do we look at the highest exponent power?

The big O of this is O(n^2)? Am i right?

Comment: I suggest taking a look here, might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it

Comment: Take a look at this answer as well - http://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/41747

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The big O of this is O(n^2)? Am i right?

No, `2^n` will be dominating over everything else, despite its tiny coefficient.